# InfoPath 2010 from dropdown list not showing choices when conditional formatting rule applied

Tags: dropdown, infopath-rules, choice-field, formatting

Another "driving me crazy"  I add a dropdown list box to my infopath form publishing to SharePoint 2013 list.  I add a formatting rule to highlight field.  Works fine in preview, when I publish to SharePoint the field highlights as it should but my dropdown choices won't show.  It appears to show inconsisently with some dropdown's working fine and some not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dropdown list property - > click on the **Browser forms** tab -> Change the **Postback settings** to **Always** from **Only when necessary(by default this will be enabled)**

[image: Infopath form dropdown list properties]

Comment: Hi - if it has helped you, could you please [Upvote(^)] and mark as answered.